# Find occurence by comparing 2 arrays

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, filter

```
function getResponseList () {
var listFormResponse = sheetNameFormResponse.getRange(2,columnOfDateTime(),sheetNameFormResponse.getLastRow()-1).getValues();
var lastRow = sheetName.getRange(2, 1).getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow();
var listAvaApointment = sheetName.getRange(2,1,lastRow).getValues();
var count = listFormResponse.filter(function(listFormResponse) {
return listFormResponse == listAvaApointment[0][0];
});
Logger.log(listFormResponse);
Logger.log(listAvaApointment[0][0]);
Logger.log(count);
}
```

I am currently using array.filter().length to find ocurrence by comparing 2 arrays. However, the filter() function is not working properly and returns nothing by comparing 2 arrays.

```
執行記錄
上午11:09:13  通知  開始執行
上午11:09:14  資訊  [[Tue Mar 29 15:00:00 GMT+08:00 2022], 
[Wed Mar 30 14:30:00 GMT+08:00 2022], 
[Wed Mar 30 16:00:00 GMT+08:00 2022], 
[Wed Mar 30 15:30:00 GMT+08:00 2022], 
[Wed Mar 30 14:30:00 GMT+08:00 2022], 
[Wed Mar 30 10:00:00 GMT+08:00 2022], 
[Wed Mar 30 10:00:00 GMT+08:00 2022], 
[Wed Mar 30 10:00:00 GMT+08:00 2022]]
上午11:09:14  資訊  Wed Mar 30 10:00:00 GMT+08:00 2022
上午11:09:14  資訊  []
上午11:09:14  通知  執行完畢
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you are comparing [] to a date object. So it does not return a match.
[ Wed Mar 30 2022 01:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) ] Wed Mar 30 2022 01:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) 'object' 'object'

```
function getResponseList () {
    var listFormResponse = sheetNameFormResponse.getRange(2,columnOfDateTime(),sheetNameFormResponse.getLastRow()-1).getValues();
    var lastRow = sheetName.getRange(2, 1).getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow();
    var listAvaApointment = sheetName.getRange(2,1,lastRow).getValues();
    var count = listFormResponse.filter(function(listFormResponse) {
    return listFormResponse[0] == listAvaApointment[0][0];
    });
    Logger.log(listFormResponse);
    Logger.log(listAvaApointment[0][0]);
    Logger.log(count);
}
```

Comment: So you mean array is not able to compare Date Object? Or how could I adjust my code to be able to run the function successfully? thank a lot

Comment: var count = listFormResponse.filter(function(listFormResponse) {
    console.log(listFormResponse,listAvaApointment[0][0],listFormResponse == listAvaApointment[0][0])
    return listFormResponse[0] == listAvaApointment[0][0];
});    You will see when you run this code. Please give it a try.

Comment: sorry after I tried your code to run my data, I still dont have any progress since no matter how many dimension for 2 arrays, it is not able to compare for my case. The difficluty I am facing is I know it should be about array dimension but I have no idea how to fix and the reason why it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Description

There is no way for me to test this because I don't know what your data is but locigally it should work.  And I don't know which element of `listFormResponse` you want to test against.

`listFormResponse` is a 2D array, so in your Array.filter callback function the parameter to the function is the row of the array, I call it formResponse.  Then formResponse is compared to the `listAvaApointment` array creating another array I'll call foundResponse containing each of the rows that passed the test.

Script

```
function getResponseList () {
  var listFormResponse = sheetNameFormResponse.getRange(2,columnOfDateTime(),sheetNameFormResponse.getLastRow()-1).getValues();
  var lastRow = sheetName.getRange(2, 1).getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow();
  var listAvaApointment = sheetName.getRange(2,1,lastRow).getValues();
  var foundResponse = listFormResponse.filter(function(formResponse) {
    formResponse[0] == listAvaApointment[0][0];
  });
  Logger.log(listFormResponse);  // A 2D array
  Logger.log(listAvaApointment[0][0]);
  Logger.log(foundResponse.length); // A 2D array
}
```

Reference

- [Array.filter()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp)

Comment: thanks for your reply. My array for listFromResponse is form an excel column ranged F2:F6 with below timeslots [2022/3/29 下午 3:00:00, 2022/3/30 下午 2:30:00, 2022/3/30 下午 4:00:00, 2022/3/30 下午 3:30:00, 2022/4/1 下午 2:30:00]. My another array listAvaApointment is a similar but longer list from another excel ranged A2:A621. It also contains timeslots with similar formate. Using your code for listFromResponse is my 1st array with 5 timeslots and listAvaApointment[0][0] is my first timeslot from 2nd array. the foundResponse.length is 0.0

Comment: `listFormResponse` is still a 2D array so the first element of `listFormResponse` is  ``listFormResponse[0][0]`  same with `listAvaAppointment`.  So I still think my code is correct.

Comment: I am exactly using your codes and below is the result: 執行記錄
下午9:12:50 通知 開始執行
下午9:12:51 資訊 [[Tue Mar 29 15:00:00 GMT+08:00 2022], [Wed Mar 30 14:30:00 GMT+08:00 2022], [Wed Mar 30 16:00:00 GMT+08:00 2022], [Wed Mar 30 15:30:00 GMT+08:00 2022], [Fri Apr 01 10:00:00 GMT+08:00 2022]]
下午9:12:51 資訊 Fri Apr 01 10:00:00 GMT+08:00 2022
下午9:12:51 資訊 0.0
下午9:12:51 通知 執行完畢
listAvaApointment[0][0]'s result is 'Fri Apr 01 10:00:00 GMT+08:00 2022' which should be 1 of the value in array listFormResponse. but the result for foundResonse.length is 0.0

Comment: So are the values in the arrays Dates?  If so try `formResponse[0].valueOf() == listAvaApointment[0][0].valueOf()`